# SP2013: Can the farm administrator modify result source "Local SharePoint Results"

Tags: result-source

I logon as farm administrator. I would like to modify the OOTB result source "Local SharePoint Results". However when I open it every field is disabled and follow warning shows:

You don't appear to have permission to view the account credentials for this result source. You need permissions at the level at which the result source was created. For example, only an account with administrator permissions for a Search Service application can view the account credentials for a result source created at that level.

I have tried add the farm admin to Search Service Application with "Full Control" but still the same.

May I know is "Local SharePoint Results" actually not editable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is locked Down by default in sharepoint 2013. As a workaround, you can make a copy of that result source the modify it.

You can point to the arrow next to an existing result source, click Copy, and then modify the copy as necessary and save it with a new name.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Microsoft is really good at throwing unrelated error message...